# Relative link in VBA for updating external links

Tags: excel, vba

I have two excel files in my drop box ( A and B ). some cells in B are linked to A.

suppose  file A is open in my computer and at the same time file B is open in **another computer** .

I make some change in file A , now I want to see these changes in file B ( which is linked to A)
so I go to

DATA tab>> Edit links>> Update values and then     file B will be updated.

so far so good

I want to create a macro for updating file B  ( instead of each time  go to DATA tab>> Edit links>> Update values)

this is the code I wrote :

```
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:= _
    "C:\Users\Win 10\Dropbox\A.xlsm", Type:=xlExcelLinks
```

The problem is that the link in this code is **absolute**. If I open file B is **any other computer** this macro wouldn't work

is there anyway to solve this issue?

Thank you so muuch

Comment: Where is the file stored/accessed from?

Comment: Try setting the path like `\\YourComputerName\Dropbox\A.xlsm" and share the "Dropbox" folder for Everybody access... Of course, using its full path: "C:\Users\Win 10\Dropbox". It should be obvious that "the other computer" must be in the same network...

Comment: It seems that functions exists to find Dropbox path based on the .json config file in AppData: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/05/05/find-your-dropbox-folder-in-vba/  (look for a comment made by Dick Kusleika). It could work and solve your problem (at least on computers running Windows) but l haven't tested it out so I can't say for sure.